# Calculated columns in pentaho Cde

Tags: pentaho

I am new to the use of Pentaho and let me know how it works the "Calculated Columns" option into "sql query" object. 
I need to calculate the average value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated columns perform basic operations on other columns, on a Row by Row basis. You cannot use that to calculate the average of all values from another column, but you can use it to calculate the average of values from the same row.

The syntax follows Open Formula syntax (the same you have on Pentaho Report Designer).

So, for example, if you have columns A, B and C as "Date", "Quantity" and "Sales", you can define a new column, "Unit Price" using the formula

```
=[Sales]/[Quantity]
```

Another situation is the following: lets say you have 13 columns: "Customer", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ...
You can create a new column, the Avg value of the 12 months, by either using the Avg function or summing all 12 values and then dividing by 12:

```
=AVG( [Jan],[Feb],[Mar], ....)
```

And the values of that new column would be the avg value of the 12 months per customer.

But each formula calculation will only use values from the same ROW or results, it cannot reference other rows of data.